# Change table index format

Tags: tables, captions, ieeetran

I am using `IEEEtran` document class. `\caption{some text}` in a `table` environment ends up `TABLE I: some text` in the final PDF. But I need `Table 1: some text`.

I managed to change `TABLE` to `Table` by `\def\tablename{Table}`, however I could not change `I` to `1`. Any idea?

Comment: you can try `\renewcommand*{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}`

Comment: The `IEEEtran` class is meant for submissions to IEEE journals or conferences. Changing the format may cause rejection.

Comment: This just came up in the tex weekly newsletter as needing an answer. However it looks like it has one. Perhaps touhami should repost as an answer and Frogatto accept it?